# mysql inner join one table on two columns

Tags: mysql

Mysql query that I use looks like this:

```
SELECT messages.*,users.name,users.pic 
FROM messages 
INNER JOIN users 
ON users.hash = '123456789' 
WHERE (( receive='987654321' AND send='123456789') 
OR (receive='123456789'  AND send='987654321' )) 
ORDER BY id_message desc
```

This query returns the correct results, but I need besides photo and the name of the person who sent the message ("pic" and "name" fields in the table) also picture and name of the person who receives the message.

The result that i need should look like:

```
  id_message  |    name  |   pic    |   messages  |   send    |   receive  
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
      4       |  john    |  1.jpg   |     text 1  | 123456789 |  987654321
      3       |  merry   |  2.jpg   |     text 2  | 987654321 |  123456789
      2       |  merry   |  2.jpg   |     text 3  | 987654321 |  123456789 
      1       |  john    |  1.jpg   |     text 4  | 123456789 |  987654321
```

What I need to modify in this query in order to receive the correct result?
I appreciate any help...

EDIT:

The "users" table:

```
   hash     |  name  |   pic  
 ------------------------------
 123456789  |  john  |   1.jpg
 987654321  |  merry |   2.jpg
```

The "messages" table:

```
   id_message  |   receive   |   send     | messages
  ---------------------------------------------------
        1      |  987654321  | 123456789  |   text 1 
        2      |  123456789  | 987654321  |   text 2 
        3      |  123456789  | 987654321  |   text 3 
        4      |  987654321  | 123456789  |   text 4
```

Comment: you mean you need the photo of the person who receives the message in the same row as the picture of the person who sent it correct? if so would that be another column (e.g. `pic_receive`) or would both pictures be listed in the same column (e.g. `pic = 1.jpg, 2.jpg`) somehow?  similar clarification for `name`.  If NOT then what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need the photo of the person who receives the message in the same row as the picture of the person who sent it then you will need to join the `users` table twice.  Also assuming you want a different column for those names and pics like below:

```
SELECT messages.*,senders.name,senders.pic, receivers.name as rec_name, receivers.pic as rec_pic 
FROM messages 
INNER JOIN users senders
ON users.hash = '123456789' 
and (( receive='987654321' AND send='123456789') 
inner join users as receivers  
on receivers.hash = messages.receive
ORDER BY id_message desc
```

Comment: I get error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join ...